# How can I show intermediate value property for this function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Intermediate value property for $f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
> \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{array} \right.$

$g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $h(x)\sin(x)$ are continuous on $]-\infty,0[ \cup]0,\infty[$

$\Rightarrow h\circ g$ is continuous  on $]-\infty,0[ \cup]0,\infty[$

$h \circ g $ has IVP on $]-\infty,0[ \cup]0,\infty[$

also $h\circ g (0) = 0$

therefore $h \circ g $ has IVP on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: if you mean mean intermediate value theorem certainly not

Comment: This function has intermediate value property right ?

Comment: so it is not possible to apply that theorem.  Do you remember the statments of that theorem?

Comment: I am using continuity implies intermediate value property.. how can I show it otherwise ?

Comment: The function is not continuous at zero or on any interval containing zero. To apply IVT you have to a continuous function in some closed and finite interval. Otherwise it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)<a<f(y)$ with $x<y$. If $x<0$ and $y>0$ then, since f attains all vales between -1 and 1 on $(o,y)$ [ in fact on $(0,\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon >0$] it does attain the value $a$ somewhere in $(x,y)$. The remaining cases are all covered by the fact that continuous functions have intermediate value property.